# Unexpected end of JSON input when trying to execute axios post request

Tags: javascript, axios, http-post

I'm getting this error -

```
"SyntaxError: C:\Users\ts\Desktop\react projects\tasks\server\cards.json: Unexpected end of JSON input"
```

I saw a lot of solutions to this error but could not come up with a solution.
I get this error when I try to add a new object to a JSON file that has an array of JSON objects.

example to the JSON file-

```json
    [{"number":12,
      "color":"blue"},
     {"number":10,
      "color":"red"}
    }]
```

Example of a card about to write to the file-

```json
    {
    "number":10,
    "color":"blue"
    }
```

Client request-

```js
    const cloneTicket = (ticket: Ticket) => {    
        axios.post(APIRoot+'/clone/card', card).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    }
```

Server -

```js
    app.post(APIPath + '/clone/card', (req, res) => {
      const cards = fs.readFileSync('cards.json');
      let cards_json = JSON.parse(cards)
      
      cards_json.push(req.body)
    
      const new_jsons = JSON.stringify(cards_json,null,2)
    
      fs.writeFileSync('cards.json', new_jsons, (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res)
      })
      res.send(new_jsons)
    })
```

cards.json file-

```
[
    {
        "number": 12,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "number": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }

]
```

And the error throwing from \server\cards.json.

Comment: That example is not valid JSON. (Edit: now it is)

Comment: please checkout json examples https://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Comment: @MetByrdy I don't get it, those examples don't use valid JSON?

Comment: Single quotes in json is not really valid also you forget one in the end of red :)

Comment: @tsilver Now that the JSON examples are correct, do you still get the same error?

Comment: yes im still getting the error

Comment: Which file is throwing the error? client or server? Can you show the actual contents of `cards.json`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the fix, change this line:

`const cards = fs.readFileSync('cards.json');`

to

`const cards = fs.readFileSync('cards.json', 'utf8');`

When you don't provide an encoding type to `readFileSync` it will return a buffer instead of the file contents. The buffer will then not be able to be `JSON.parse()`ed correctly.

Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: The error might not be with your example JSON file then. What error do you get?

Comment: I added the updated JSON file to the original question message

Comment: What does `cards` have in it? Can you do a console.log and share the output please? Directly from the console

Comment: cards=  <Buffer 5b 7b 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 22 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 22 3a 31 32 2c 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 22 63 6f 6c 6f 72 22 3a 22 72 65 64 22 0d 0a 7d 2c 0d 0a 7b 0d 0a 20 20 ... 40 more bytes>
cards_json=  [ { number: 12, color: 'red' }, { number: 10, color: 'blue' } ]

Comment: Notice the single quote for `red` and `blue`

Comment: It should be: `[ { "number": 12, "color": "red" }, {"number": 10, "color": "blue" } ]`

Comment: req.body =  {
  number: 10,
  color: 'blue'
}

Comment: Yes, i understand that. but in JSON they with double quote

Comment: The request body needs to be valid JSON as well. req.body = { "number": 10, "color": "blue" } ... Note the difference in quotes